# Get Debugger Raw View properties

Tags: wpf, debugging

```
public class CompositeCollectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values
            , Type targetType
            , object parameter
            , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var res = new CompositeCollection();
            foreach (var item in values)
                if (item is IEnumerable && item != null)
                {
                    res.Add(new CollectionContainer()
                    {
                        Collection = item as IEnumerable 
                    });
                }

            return res;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value
            , Type[] targetTypes
            , object parameter
            , System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }`your text`
```

I have implemented a CompositeCollectionConverter implementing IMultiValueConverter, While I am getting the objects in values array in Convert method, I can see the items properties that are there in Raw View in debugging mode but not able to cast and access the item's properties.

Get Raw View Properties.

Answer (score -1):

The debugger uses reflection to get the properties and other members.

You can get the type of the item and then get its properties something like this:

```
var type = item.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(item);
}
```